# azure servicebus maxConcurrentCalls totally ignored

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

I have thsese in my host.json but every time i run the function it runs in parallel runing much more threads then 1 ( so much as there are messages in queue)

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

my function

```
 [FunctionName(nameof(ResourceEventProcessorFunction))]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]Message message, IMessageSession messageSession, ILogger log)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so the problem was that every message had a differnet sessionId.
Disabling sessionId on subscription in azure solved this problem.

In details below for bounty :D
azure docs doesnt exactly specify how to limit thread number, but I looked a bit dipper.

there is [`MessageRecievePump`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/MessageReceivePump.cs)
and
[`SessionRecievePump`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus/src/SessionReceivePump.cs)
one uses `MaxConcurrentCalls` the other one `MaxConcurrentSessions` and `MaxConcurrentAcceptSessionCalls`

be aware of this if you include session in your subscription (MaxConcurrentCalls doesnt work) it works only when session id is the same.
when session is differnt try to use MaxConcurrentSessions or MaxConcurrentAcceptSessionCalls but be aware there are no docs about this....

Comment: This only works if you have a dedicated App Service Plan with a single instance, right? For anything else, you would need to either use the Singleton attribute or use the **same** sessionId for all messages. See also my answer.

Answer (score 6):

#### Leveraging sessions

Since you are using sessions, you can use the same sessionId for all messages, and they will be processed in order by a single instance, regardless of the settings in your host.json.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions

#### Using `Singleton` attribute

If you can't use the sessionId for your purpose, you should try the `[Singleton]` attribute on your function. This will ensure that only one instance across all of your function instances will process the request.

We have this working successfully for WebJobs in production, and it should work just the same for Azure Functions. If you have dedicated app service plans, using this attribute should be enough. *This is not recommended for a consumption plan*.

> `[Singleton]` **does** work on functions. The Azure Function host will create or wait for a lock in the Azure Storage account. The lock is the host ID which should be the same for all hosts of an app across all instances - so all instances share this lock and will only allow one execution to occur at a time.
>
> To test this I put 1000 queue messages at once on a function with [Singleton]. The function would wake up, emit the invocation ID, sleep, and then emit the invocation ID. After processing all 1000 I looked at logs and never saw invocation IDs overlap. Only one invocation would happen globally at a time.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912#issuecomment-419608830

```cs
 [Singleton]
 [FunctionName(nameof(ResourceEventProcessorFunction))]
    public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%TopicName%", "%SubscriptionName%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection", IsSessionsEnabled = true)]Message message, IMessageSession messageSession, ILogger log)
```

#### In a consumption plan

Continuing the quote above:

> With that said I think the recommendation is: [Singleton] isn't recommended for consumption hosted function plans. If you have a dedicated app service plan it's fine (as you are paying for the instance anyway). If you want to enforce [Singleton] like behavior in a consumption plan you are likely best to:
>
> 1. Set `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to 1 so you never scale to more than one instance
> 2. Set the `host.json` file to only allow 1 concurrent execution at a time for that trigger (for instance a batch size of 1 for Azure Queues).

https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/912#issuecomment-419608830

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 1,
      "messageHandlerOptions": {
        "maxConcurrentCalls": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can set `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to 1 to make the function run only one instance at a time.

If you develop locally, you can set it in `local.settings.json`, if you develop in `Azure portal`, you can set it in `Configuration -> Application settings`.

**Note：**

**1.** If you set `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to 1, your function will not scale out and can only run in one instance.

**2.** In addition to setting `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT`, you still need to set `maxConcurrentCalls` to 1

**3.** This setting is in preview. [An app property for function max scale out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#limit-scale-out) has been added and is the recommended way to limit scale out.

For more details, you can refer to this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#website_max_dynamic_application_scale_out).

Comment: Please try this [setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSnke.png).

Comment: thanks Frank but it didn't worked as well. Tried this even allreday. Don't know why but I cant controll number of messages process in paralell

Comment: Sorry for not helping you solve the problem. I encountered a problem before using `[assembly:FunctionsStartup(typeof(Startup)` to cause `host.json` to fail. You can see if [it](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4480) is related to this.

Comment: it doesnt even recognize FunctionsStartup , but your case was eventhub , my is servicebus

Comment: from what i understand, if you're on consumption, you do not have the ability to enforce that the function runs ONLY once because it may be running on multiple VMs. is this correct? if so, then `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` will not be affective at ensuring just 1 instance, however it WILL ensure 1 instance per node (vm)

Comment: @FrankGong please provide input on my comment above